# Access Denied when accessing non-root url using S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have an question concerning AWS s3 and cloudfront.
I host the build of a private page (vue-app) on s3 and access it via cloudfront (I wrote a permission in the S3 bucket using the OAI from a cloudfront-origin.). Everything works well: When I call the root url (`xxx.cloudfront.net/`) I can access my webapp. When I call this url my webapp adds to the root-url: '`app/documents`' and loads the content.
But I assume that sometimes user try to directly access the url: '`xxx.cloudfront.net/app/documents`'. Up to now this does not work: I get an `AccessDenied` (from S3).
What should I do?
My goal is that when someone enters a specific domain (not the root domain, for example: `xxx.cloudfront.net/app/documents/4`, he will be able to directly access the document with the id 4. Is something like this possible?

PS: I already took a look at the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453548/static-site-works-in-my-s3-instance-but-with-cloudfront-im-getting-an-error-403) but this does not work for me. If I use a custom domain, I do not get an `Origin Access Identity` which I use in the permission file in S3 (so that only cloudfront can access the s3 code).
I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017105/how-do-you-set-a-default-root-object-for-subdirectories-for-a-statically-hosted/49742870#49742870) which seems to be very similar. This recommends to append an index.html to every request. Maybe I do not have the knowledge but in my S3-bucket is only one index.html (the root one). How could this then work?

Thank you and all the best,
Lukas

Comment: Have you found an answer??? I'm still wrestling with this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your S3 bucket public.

You can follow this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

You need to open the S3 ACL and make your object public.